# C++ version of CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: c++

Java has [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which enables me to iterate and mutate using 2 different threads simultaneously, without having any external locking.

Do we have any similar thread safety data structure for C++?

Comment: i think you will need to create one yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library which would support this.  Given
the interface to C++ standard containers, I'm not sure it's possible.
You'd have to start with something like:

```
template <typename T>
class CopyOnWriteVector
{
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<T> > myData;
    void uniqueCopy()
    {
        myData = boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<T> >( new std::vector<T>( *myData ) );
    }
public:
    //  ...
    //  for example...
    void push_back( T const& newElement )
    {
        uniqueCopy();
        myData->push_back( newElement );
    }
    //  Similar for all other non-const functions.
    //  const functions just forward, without the call to
    uniqueCopy.
};
```

This doesn't work, however, for functions which return handles to some
internal data: either iterators or references to elements.  For
iterators, it would be possible to create an iterator which contains
a `shared_ptr` to the container it iterates into, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
class CopyOnWriteVector
{
    //  ...
public:
    class iterator : public std::random_access_iterator_tag
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<T> > myVector;
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator myImpl;
    public:
        iterator() {}  //  for convenience...
        iterator( boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<T> > const& vector,
                  typename std::vector<T>::iterator initialValue )
            : myVector( vector )
            , myImpl( initialValue )
        {
        }
        //  All other iterator functions forward directly to myImpl
    };
};
```

The functions which return references are another issue; you can't
replace the reference with a smart reference, or a proxy of any type.

(Note: all of the above code is just off the top of my head, and probably contains significant errors.  It's just to give an idea of the direction you might take.)